# Random unique string generation to use as nonce (oauth)

Tags: ios, swift, nonce

I am trying to use the UUID to generate as a nonce to be use for Twitter reverse authentication. But apparently the UUID is not a good choice. So how can I generate a unique random string every time stripping out all non-word characters, taking care that it gets release from memory after use. The following code crashes.

```
    var uuid: CFUUIDRef = CFUUIDCreate(nil)
    var nonce: CFStringRef = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuid)
    CFRelease(uuid)

    println("createdNonce:\(nonce)")
```

**EDIT:**
I am on xcode6 beta2, and i can't debug, and xocde crashes, any chance it gets. So well, the CFRelease part is crashing for me. Once I remove, it seems to work fine, but I dont know if this will create a memory leak.

As to why UUID's might not be a good choice to use for nonce it seems is because, UUID's are not made of true random bits, referring this discussion here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/30

Comment: Look at `NSUUID` instead, it's ObjC and thus more Swift-friendly. And why not just generate a random string for nonce?

Comment: Can you clarify why you think the UUID is a bad choice?  This code worked fine for me in a Swift playground.  Can you share more details about the crash?

Comment: added info @AaronGolden

Comment: @srinivas refer my answer about crash

Comment: @srinivas UUID v4 (which I assume `CFUUID` uses, v4 are the random ones) gives 122 random bits out of 128. Depending on your needs, this might be enough. Assuming you don't serialize it as hex, of course.

Comment: @Krumelur yes that seems random enough :D. I wanted to see if UUID is the standard way to generate a nonce string.

Comment: See my answer about generating a nonce using Sec* API. Beware that serializing the UUID as hex does not give you full entropy per character. See the API documentation for the Twitter service you are using for what it expects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A more correct way of generation a nonce would probably be to generate random bytes using a cryptographic RNG. iOS just happens to have such a thing:

```
var s = NSMutableData(length: 32)
SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, UInt(s.length), UnsafePointer<UInt8>(s.mutableBytes))

// s is now a NSData containing 32 random bytes
```

Then convert to a string using whatever format the API suggests (probably Base64), e.g.

```
let base64str = s.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(0)
```

EDIT: The approach above seems to be the one Twitter uses in the docs. See [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request). I can't say if UUIDS are more easily predicted. It depends on the method they are generated. SecRandomCopyBytes seems to be used for cryptographic purposes though, so it should be safe to use.

Comment: Lots has changed in Swift. Looks more like this now: `SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, s!.length, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(s!.mutableBytes))` and `let base64String = s!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(0))`

Answer (score 6):

With SwiftUI 5.x and CryptoKit, it is easy:

```
import CryptoKit

let nonce = ChaChaPoly.Nonce.init()
```

in use:

```
let encryptedContent = try! ChaChaPoly.seal(inputBuffer, using: symmetricKey, nonce: ChaChaPoly.Nonce.init()).combined
```

Comment: Is there a way just to get a nonce string?

Comment: @Zorayr Simple string `Data(ChaChaPoly.Nonce()).base64EncodedString()`

Comment: Any way to control the length of generated nonce?

Answer (score 3):

One example that's provided by [Firebase's Authenticating Using Apple tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple):

```
// Adapted from https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/nonce#generate-a-cryptographically-random-nonce
private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
  precondition(length > 0)
  let charset: Array<Character> =
      Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
  var result = ""
  var remainingLength = length

  while remainingLength > 0 {
    let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
      var random: UInt8 = 0
      let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
      if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
        fatalError("Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)")
      }
      return random
    }

    randoms.forEach { random in
      if remainingLength == 0 {
        return
      }

      if random < charset.count {
        result.append(charset[Int(random)])
        remainingLength -= 1
      }
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is crashing because you are calling `CFRelease`.In `swift` there is no need to call `CFRelease`.From [swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)

> Core Foundation objects returned from annotated APIs are automatically
>   memory managed in Swift—you do not need to invoke the CFRetain,
>   CFRelease, or CFAutorelease functions yourself.

```
    var uuid: CFUUIDRef = CFUUIDCreate(nil)
    var nonce: CFStringRef = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuid)
   //Remove this swift will manage the memory managment.This line is causing crash  
   //CFRelease(uuid) 
    println("createdNonce:\(nonce)")
```

this code will work fine.**No this will not create memory leak swift will manage that**

Comment: Had completely missed that Swift manages CF objects automagically. One more reason to push for Swift then :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that works in Swift 4:

```
func generateNonce(lenght: Int) throws -> Data {
    let nonce = NSMutableData(length: lenght)
    let result = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, nonce!.length, nonce!.mutableBytes)
    if result == errSecSuccess {
        return nonce! as Data
    } else {
        throw Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a perfect solution but want to suggest it because it will take a lot of Twitter reverse auth madness for you..

Try to use cocoapod TWReverseAuth

Comment: I was doing it wrong earlier. Now I generate the x_reverse_auth token on server and which the mobile client calls, and then uses SLRequest to authenticate with twitter. I extended j7mbo/twitter-php-app to do twitter reverse auth. here is the lib: https://github.com/srinivasmangipudi/twitter-api-php

Answer (score 0):

Here is a easier way to do this then:

```
    var temp = NSUUID.UUID().UUIDString
    var nonce = temp.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
    println("createdNonce:\(nonce)")
```